# Setup timeout parametr in QGIS PostgreSQL connection

Tags: qgis, postgresql

Is it possible to setup timeout parameter for PostgreSQL in QGIS PostgreSQL / PostGIS connection?

I want to change default timeout value (infinity timeout) for DB connection in QGIS.

In GUI I did not find any paremeter:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default network connection timeout is 60 seconds, and can be changed in the Settings:

[image]

I think DB connections also honour this value.